# XSLT: Mathematical addition of elements based on 2 child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, math, recursion, addition

I am trying to add transactions based on the account number and the currency associated with the amount.

Here is the original xml:
I expect there to be at most 1000 transactions. In the example I have 5 transactions from 2 accounts in AUD and HKD. I would like all the amounts, per currency, per transaction to be added as 1 line.

```
<transactionlist>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <amount>100</amount>
        <currency>AUD</currency>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <amount>50</amount>
        <currency>AUD</currency>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <amount>100</amount>
        <currency>HKD</currency>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <amount>500</amount>
        <currency>HKD</currency>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>2</accountnumber>
        <amount>200</amount>
        <currency>AUD</currency>
    </transaction>
</transactionlist>
```

This is the expected output (count being how many transactions were added to create that new row):

```
<transactionlist>
    <row>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <totalamount>150</totalamount>
        <currency>AUD</currency>
        <count>2</count>
    </row>
    <row>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <totalamount>600</totalamount>
        <currency>HKD</currency>
        <count>2</count>
    </row>
    <row>
        <accountnumber>2</accountnumber>
        <totalamount>200</totalamount>
        <currency>AUD</currency>
        <count>1</count>
    </row>
</transactionlist>
```

Here is how far I got. Just not sure how to go about only adding by the currency for each transaction grouped by account

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <transactionlist>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="transactionlist/transaction" />
    </transactionlist>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="transaction">
    <!-- only do work for the *first* transaction with any particular ID -->
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::transaction/accountnumber = current()/accountnumber)">
      <row>
        <xsl:copy-of select="accountnumber" />
        <totalamount>
          <xsl:call-template name="running-total-byaccount">
            <xsl:with-param name="values" select="/transactionlist/transaction[accountnumber = current()/accountnumber]" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </totalamount>
      </row>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="running-total-byaccount">
    <xsl:param name="values" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count($values)">
        <xsl:variable name="curr" select="$values[1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="rest" select="$values[position() &gt; 1]" />
        <!-- recursive step: calculate the total of all remaining values -->
        <xsl:variable name="subtotal">
          <xsl:call-template name="running-total-byaccount">
            <xsl:with-param name="values" select="$rest" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$subtotal + $curr/amount" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="0" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've gone far too deep with an imperative "programming-like" approach to using XSLT.  I recommend to my students that a declarative, top-down approach using a grouping methodology is the best way to approach a requirement such as yours.

Of the grouping methodologies for XSLT 1.0, your problem suggests to me the variable-based grouping methodology because of the nested nature of the groups.  XSLT 2.0 makes this easier, but you've declared XSLT 1.0 in your stylesheet so I've assumed that is a limitation for you.

A quick solution I threw together is in the transcript below. I hope this helps. You can see it avoids all the issues of recursion and breaks down the requirement into a grouping problem.

Data:

```
T:\ftemp>type currency.xml 
<transactionlist>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <amount>100</amount>
        <currency>AUD</currency>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <amount>50</amount>
        <currency>AUD</currency>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <amount>100</amount>
        <currency>HKD</currency>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
        <amount>500</amount>
        <currency>HKD</currency>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <accountnumber>2</accountnumber>
        <amount>200</amount>
        <currency>AUD</currency>
    </transaction>
</transactionlist>
```

Execution and results:

```
T:\ftemp>call xslt currency.xml currency.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transactionlist>
   <row>
      <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
      <totalamount>150</totalamount>
      <currency>AUD</currency>
      <count>2</count>
   </row>
   <row>
      <accountnumber>1</accountnumber>
      <totalamount>600</totalamount>
      <currency>HKD</currency>
      <count>2</count>
   </row>
   <row>
      <accountnumber>2</accountnumber>
      <totalamount>200</totalamount>
      <currency>AUD</currency>
      <count>1</count>
   </row>
</transactionlist>
```

Stylesheet:

```
T:\ftemp>type currency.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="transactionlist">
  <transactionlist>
    <xsl:variable name="trans" select="transaction"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$trans">
      <!--find all unique accounts-->
      <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=
             generate-id($trans[accountnumber=current()/accountnumber][1])">
        <xsl:variable name="acc" 
                    select="$trans[accountnumber=current()/accountnumber]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$acc">
          <!--find all unique currencies in the accounts-->
          <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=
                        generate-id($acc[currency=current()/currency][1])">
            <!--note all for the given currency-->
            <xsl:variable name="curr"
                          select="$acc[currency=current()/currency]"/>
            <row>
              <xsl:copy-of select="accountnumber"/>
              <totalamount>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($curr/amount)"/>
              </totalamount>
              <xsl:copy-of select="currency"/>
              <count>
                <xsl:value-of select="count($curr)"/>
              </count>
            </row>            
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </transactionlist>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edited: repaired typos and collected currency values for readability.

Comment: Genius! I don't know how I got myself all turned around and upside down. You said students, so I am assuming you are a lecturer. You would not happen to have free content online somewhere that I can use to better understand XSLT would you?

Comment: I've been privileged to teach XSLT around the world since before XSLT was finalized in 1999, and I was the founding chairman of the OASIS Technical Committee for XSLT and XPath Conformance.  Yes, five hours of my video instruction is available for free streaming.  I've updated my StackOverflow profile with information not suitable to be posted in a question forum.  Good luck in your work with XML!